# Bug when sorting std::deque

Tags: c++, sorting, std, visual-studio-2022, deque

When compiling a C++ project in release mode with Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6.4 with the ‘Inline function expansion’ option set to /Ob2, i have found out that the `std::sort()` function for `std::deque` returns incorrect results. I have tried with the current version of Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.9) and the problem still occurs.

The code to reproduce this problem is as following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const string data[] = {
        "ElectronicDocument",
        "Order",
        "xs:string",
        "an..10",
        "DateTime",
        "Date",
        "DeliveryDateRequested",
        "CurrencyCode",
        "Party",
        "BuyerParty",
        "EAN - 13",
        "xs:positiveInteger",
        "xs:nonNegativeInteger",
        "xs:integer",
        "xs:decimal",
        "GLN",
        "Contact",
        "an..35",
        "EMail",
        "TelephoneOrTelefaxNumber",
        "Address",
        "an..70",
        "CityName",
        "n5",
        "xs:nonPositiveInteger",
        "PostalCode",
        "CountryCode",
        "SellerParty",
        "BankAccountIdentification",
        "n..12",
        "LineItem",
        "n..5",
        "GTIN",
        "MonetaryAmount",
        "Price",
        "MonetaryAmountValue",
        "Quantity",
        "MeasureUnitCode",
        "TotalAmount"
    };

    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<string>> tDeque;
    for (auto iter = std::begin(data); iter < std::end(data); iter++)
    {
        tDeque.push_back(std::make_unique<string>(*iter));
    }

    std::sort(tDeque.begin(), tDeque.end(), 
        [](const std::unique_ptr<string>& l, const std::unique_ptr<string>& r) -> bool
        {
            return *l < *r;
        });

    for (auto iter = tDeque.begin(); iter < tDeque.end(); iter++)
    {
        cout << (*iter)->c_str() << "\r\n";
    }
}
```

With the compiler option /Ob2 produces `std::sort()` function results that are in an incorrect order, as shown below.

```
Address
BankAccountIdentification
CityName
CountryCode
GTIN
LineItem
MeasureUnitCode
MonetaryAmount
MonetaryAmountValue
PostalCode
Price
Quantity
SellerParty
TelephoneOrTelefaxNumber
BuyerParty
Contact
CurrencyCode
Date
DateTime
DeliveryDateRequested
EAN - 13
EMail
ElectronicDocument
GLN
Order
Party
TotalAmount
an.. 10
an.. 35
an.. 70
n.. 12
n.. 5
n5
xs:decimal
xs:integer
xs:nonNegativeInteger
xs:nonPositiveInteger
xs:positiveInteger
xs:string
```

Without using /Ob2, returns the `std::sort()` function results in correct order. Using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<string>>` or `std::deque<string>` instead of `std::deque<std::unique_ptr<string>>` does not lead to problem.

Can anyone confirm whether this is an error in the std library in Visual Studio? I have posted the problem in the Visual Studio Developer Community, but there has been no response.

Because of this error we can not update Visual Studio and its build tools to current version.

Comment: FWIW you should be using a `std::deque<string>` instead of a `std::deque<std::unique_ptr<string>>`.  Why are you using the latter?

Comment: OT: Please use [range `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead. And why are you printing `(*iter)->c_str()` instead of `**iter`? There also no need to use `"\r\n"` if you're just printing to a normal terminal. Plain `'\n'` will work just fine. If it's needed for your system, the carriage-return will be added automatically.

Comment: Oh (also OT), and there's no need to specify the lambda return type if it can be easily deduced (like in your case). And depending on which version of the C++ standard your compiler is using, you could replace e.g. `const std::unique_ptr<string>& l` with `const auto &l`.

Comment: I've just tried like this `cl /EHsc /std:c++20 foo.cpp /Ob2` with MSVC `19.38.33133` and can't repro.

Comment: Does not reproduce with "Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.7.1".  Is this really all the code? Because the problem might well be in another part of your real code that has UB (when you have UB somewhere the generated code may well be incorrect)

Comment: Also cannot reproduce, VS2022 (64-bit) v17.9.2 here

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedbacks. The code above is only to reproduce the problem. Infact instead of string is a structure.

i have compiled the code with following options.
CL.exe /c /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /O2 /Ob2 /Oi /Ot /Oy
  /GL /D WIN32 /D NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /Gm- /EHsc /MD /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /std:c++20 /permissive- /Fo"Release\\
  " /Fd"Release\vc143.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TP /analyze- /FC /errorReport:queue TestSortDeque.cpp

Comment: @user20061027 This may be a debugging issue, such as accidentally running a stale build. Try making a clean build.

Comment: i have tried a clean build but the result does not changed. Without /Ob2 or using std::vector instead of std::deque does not lead to problem.

Comment: @user20061027 Are you testing with the code provided, or your own (more complete) code? The problem may lie in what wasn't shown. Providing a https://godbolt.org/ example showing your problem would make it much easier to help with your issue.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux that's likely to be difficult now that godbolt doesn't support running msvc code any more

Comment: i have posted the complete solution as zip file in visual studio community. You can down load it from this link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Critical-issue-with-the-sorting-of-std::/10409415

please let me know, if you can download it. It not, i will make it available per github

Comment: @François Andrieux I have tested with the code provided. In our project the code is more complicated, so that i have prepared the provided code above to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Cannot duplicate, even when using your solution you gave to Microsoft.  I am using Visual Studio 2022, Version 17.9.1.  BTW, you are missing `#include <memory>`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for your trying. Did you build the solution as release? The problem occurs only in release mode.

Comment: I built the release version for 64-bit, and there was no issue.  I just tried with the 32-bit, and I see the error.  You should mention to Microsoft to build a 32-bit program, since the issue is not duplicated with 64-bit.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i have tested with Visual Studio 2022 17.9.3. My build options is as following.
/permissive- /ifcOutput "TestSortDeque\Release\" /GS /GL /analyze- /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Ob2 /sdl /Fd"TestSortDeque\Release\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy /Oi /MD /std:c++20 /FC /Fa"TestSortDeque\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"TestSortDeque\Release\" /Ot /Fp"TestSortDeque\Release\TestSortDeque.pch" /diagnostics:column

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Confirmed I can also only reproduce this issue on 32bit builds

Comment: A workaround could be to replace `sort` with `stable_sort` which does not seem to exhibit the same issue on 32 bit.

Comment: why do you build a 32-bit version nowadays?

Comment: In addition, the problem only occurs in C++20.